# How to preserve indent after pressing Esc in Vim

Tags: vim

I have `set autoindent`
I go to a line, press A and `<CR>` which gets me to the next line and inserts an indent. However if I press Esc the cursor jumps to the beginning of the line and the indent is gone.
I have to go about and press tabs to get to the right place again.

I know the help says:

```
If you do not type anything on the new line except <BS> or CTRL-D and then type
<Esc>, CTRL-O or <CR>, the indent is deleted again.
```

Is there a way to disable this, or at least a workaround?

Comment: Argh. +1 to this, it's really annoying. Come on, VIM. We're not in 1985 anymore, we have gigabytes of RAM and terabyes of storage, we can spare a few bytes of extra spaces on blank lines in our text files to spare the programmer some hassle.

Comment: For anyone interested, the help doc is from option `autoindent`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I figured this out.

Based on Edan Maor's answer, <kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>cc</kbd> should enter insert mode with the proper level of indentation.
...except when it doesn't :)

This works under two circumstances.

- when `cindent` is set, it will insert indent based on C formatting rules
  This may prove annoying when editing non C-like files.
- when `indentexpr` is set.

I found that the best solution is to have this is my `.vimrc`

```
set autoindent
set indentexpr=GetIndent()

function GetIndent()
   let lnum = prevnonblank(v:lnum - 1)
   let ind = indent(lnum)
   return ind
endfunction
```

Now when I press <kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>cc</kbd>, it will insert the same indent as on the previous non-blank line.

Comment: I downvoted this answer by mistake 10 hours ago (my intention was to upvote it), and now I'm unable to switch my vote until the answer is edited. :(

Answer (score 9):

I had this exact problem until two days ago.

There is **no** way to disable this, but luckily, you don't need to, because instead:

**Enter insert mode with `S` or `cc`**. Entering insert mode again with `S` will enter insert mode with the proper level of indentation, making the fact that Vim deleted the indents unimportant.

**Note:** I found that this trick worked for me most places. But for some reason, it did *not* work with Python files. I'm guessing it's something to do with the Python filetype messing with its own indentation functions, or something along those lines.

Edit:

Another trick, you can define cpoptions in a way that, if you're on a line with an indent and *move the cursor*, it will preserve the indent. This *won't* solve your problem of hitting `Esc` right away, but it's a related issue that might also be bothering you.

Comment: S or cc...doesn't work (if I already pressed Esc). I'm still stuck at the beginning of the line. Is there a specific setting for this?

Comment: No, should work out of the box. You do need to have auto-indent on, which I assume you do from the question.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is to press '.' (or any char), escape, then press x to remove the char. The indent should be preserved.

Comment: I don't like it, but if there's no better way...I guess I'm stuck with this

Comment: This method seems to work consistently whereas the 'cc' approach described in the accepted answer does not appear to work for Python files.

Answer (score 3):

type your text then press `==` in normal mode in that line

Comment: This is very handy. It indents the current line in normal mode. See also https://vimtricks.com/p/vimtrick-indenting-code/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19945/auto-indent-format-code-for-vim

Answer (score 3):

consider I use 'o' to start a newline. I add below config in _vimrc(notice I have ':set autoindent')

```
" ugly hack to start newline and keep indent
nnoremap o ox<BS>
nnoremap O Ox<BS>
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth noting that with proper plugins `S` and `cc` seem to work properly again. It is most likely python-mode that is fixing this.

https://github.com/klen/python-mode

Answer (score 0):

I had want to achieve the same effect, but because I want [the plugin showing indent](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine) to work properly. This is my workaround: I've found that `<enter>` in normal mode is almost useless. It only moves the cursor one line down, which could be achieved by `j`.

So I added this in my `.vimrc`:

```
nmap <cr> o.<c-h><esc>
```

Whenever I need a blank line for its indentation, I'd use `<enter>` instead.